# No URL to redirect to. Either provide a url or define a get_absolute_url method on the Model

Tags: python, django

Использую CreateView для генерации моделей:

```
class Create(CreateView):
    form_class = user.CreatePerson
    template_name = 'welcome.html'
    succes_url = '/success/'                                    # reverse_lazy('contact') или reverse

    def form_valid(self, form):
        Profile.objects.create(**form.cleaned_data)
        suc = self.get_success_url()
        #contact_name = self.form.cleaned_data['contact_name']
        return redirect(suc)
```

В шаблоне он же:

```
<body>

    <form method="post">{% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <input type="submit" value="Save">
    </form>
    
</body>
```

Не указываю у формы action, т.к. предполагаю, что в случае успешной валидации сайт переадресует меня по ссылке, заданной в succes_url моего класса, унаследованного от CreateView. Но после успешной валидации джанго ругается следующим текстом на строчку `suc = self.get_success_url()`:

```
No URL to redirect to.  Either provide a url or define a get_absolute_url method on the Model.
```

Погуглив немного, обнаружил советы в [духе](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24271784/django-either-provide-a-url-or-define-a-get-absolute-url-method-on-the-model) и сделал в модели самый простой метод, который только смог придумать:

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return '/success/'
```

В url-ах у меня

```
url(r'^success/$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="gradulations.htm")),
```

Но ошибка осталась. Что мне можно предпринять, чтобы от нее уйти?

Answer (score 2):

Похоже на опечатку в строке 4:

```
succes_url = '/success/'
```

Должно быть `success_url`.